# What time of events is given for probes a long way away from Earth?

Tags: probe, time, uncrewed-spaceflight

Philae is to land on 67P/Churyumov-Gerasimenko today at 17:02 CET. The comet is currently 3.409AU away from Earth. That means signals from the lander take a little over 28 minutes to reach Earth. Does that mean we get the first confirmation of landing no sooner than at 16:30 UTC, 28 minutes past planned 16:02 landing, or do we get them at 16:02, while the landing took place earlier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Rosetta website](http://rosetta.esa.int/) and live commentary has confirmed that communication of the touchdown is expected around 16:00 UTC, which implies touchdown just after 15:30 UTC comet local time.

I agree that initially the wording on the website was not clear, but now we have definite commentary.

[Abby's Post on Astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/2464/43) has more info.